# Why is my own webserver is slow with Chrome, fast with Firefox? "Initial connection" for every request ~300ms

Tags: google-chrome, http, tcp

To learn about HTTP and to solve a problem I have, I wrote my own web server for internal use.

I noticed that Chrome is significantly slower than Firefox or my mobile browser. It turns out that Chrome takes 300 ms per request's "initial connection" and Firefox does not, for *almost* every request, consistently.

FWIW, I implemented this with Python sockets, with timeouts, and multiple *persistent* threads.

Now don't kill me for this, but I haven't implemented Connection: keep-alive. I feel that if this is fast in Firefox, it can be fast in Chrome. Chrome is doing something weird with the connection and I don't know how to remove this delay. Googling this problem is very difficult because nobody uses this exact wording or means the same thing.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Firefox:

[image: FireFox]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, O-M-G. In Chrome, if I write my address:

```
http://127.0.0.1/
```

it's fast!

If I write my address:

```
http://localhost/
```

it's slow. This does not affect Firefox.